# Camel Thread Id changing when calling http component

Tags: java, redis, apache-camel

My route is like this:

```
from(rabbitmq).
to(redisLockerProcessor).
to(processor1).
to(ahc://http:).to(processor2)
.to(redisLockReleaseProcessor)
```

I am using redisson library which stores thread id which took the lock in redis. But in `redisLockReleaseProcessor` it is throwing exception that `thread id is not same as thread id which took the lock`. How does http components thread work in camel? I though the whole route runs in same thread. How can we solve the redis problem here if the whole route doesn't run in same thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

camel-ahc component is using non-blocking invocation, so  the thread could be change in your camel route. You can consider to store the thread id as the exchange property (you can use it to release the redisLock in redisLockReleaseProcessor) or use other camel http component such as camel-http which is using block API to send the request.